# Laravel Font face in layout and other blade

Tags: fonts, laravel

I have layout view with one css and two fonts in header, and yield header for another blade views:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style1.css') }}
@yield('header')
<style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family:nav-font; src: url('font/brandon_grotesque_medium.ttf'); }</style>
<style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family:Noto-Sans; src: url('font/NotoSans-Bold.ttf'); }</style>
```

They both work fine in in this layout view. But i have another view:

```
@extends('layout')
@section('header')
{{ HTML::style('css/posts/style2.css') }}
@stop
@section('content')
    My content here.
@stop
```

style2 Css works fine in my second view, but fonts are missing. I have tried to put font scripts in header section in my second view, but still nothing. What can be the problem?

Comment: I get the answer. If i use font in second view, then font location have changed, besauce second view is in another folder, so my answer is <style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family:Noto-Sans; src: url('../font/NotoSans-Bold.ttf'); }</style>

Comment: or if your font folder is at root of webserver you can just do url(/font/...) from anywhere

Comment: i'd use `URL::to('/font/NotoSans-Bold.ttf')` instead using relative sorcery.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `asset()` [Helper](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls) for an example.

```
<style type="text/css">@font-face { 
    font-family:nav-font; src: url('{{ asset('font/brandon_grotesque_medium.ttf') }}'); 
}</style>
<style type="text/css">@font-face { 
    font-family:Noto-Sans; src: url('{{ asset('font/NotoSans-Bold.ttf') }}'); 
}</style>
```

This type of approach will remove the need for the relative pathing as it will resolve to an absolute Url. 
This will remove the "relative sorcery" as zwacky had mentioned in the comments.